# Making links with spaces in a UITextView - iOS Swift

Tags: swift, hyperlink, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a UITextView with clickable links in it. The links are created by searching through the text for certain words or phrases contained in the placesArray as shown below:

```
for place in placesArray {
    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: place)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Bold", size:16.0)!, range: range)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: place, range: range)
}
```

Everything works fine except when the link is created from a phrase that has spaces in it, like "the Sea of Galilee". When I click this link, the app crashes. Nothing shows up in the debug window, but I do see a "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1007efc14)" in my AppDelegate. How can I fix this?

Comment: If the app crash, there should be an error message, which one?

Comment: I edited the question to include the error message.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have same question! Thx

Answer (score 0):

place.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
or make linkable url (remove white space or else)

Answer (score 0):

I found a alternative solution, just remove the spaces like this

```
for place in placesArray {
    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: place)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Bold", size:16.0)!, range: range)

--> let newPlace = place.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

    attributedText.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: newPlace, range: range)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `addingPercentEncoding`:

```
for place in placesArray {

    let value = place.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: place)

    attributedText?.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Bold", size:16.0)!, range: range)
    attributedText?.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: value!, range: range)

}
```